# How can I install PyGObject correctly?

Tags: python, pip, pygobject

When I install this package with "pip install pygobject" the following error occurs:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'd:\python\py\python.exe' 'd:\python\py\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' build_wheel 'C:\Users\26959\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpp6orgqvx'
           cwd: C:\Users\26959\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-28wd7uv5\pygobject_6da0a51b9af049888ec59e96d5591943
      Complete output (42 lines):
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat\generictreemodel.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
      copying pygtkcompat\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\pygtkcompat
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\docstring.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\importer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\module.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\pygtkcompat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\types.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\_constants.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\_error.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\_gtktemplate.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\_option.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\_ossighelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\_propertyhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\_signalhelper.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      copying gi\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\repository
      copying gi\repository\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\repository
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\Gdk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\GdkPixbuf.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\GIMarshallingTests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\Gio.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\GLib.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\GObject.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\Gtk.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\keysyms.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\Pango.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      copying gi\overrides\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\gi\overrides
      running build_ext
      pycairo: new API
      pycairo: trying include directory: 'C:\\Users\\26959\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-jagfh_2a\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\cairo\\include'
      pycairo: found 'C:\\Users\\26959\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-env-jagfh_2a\\overlay\\Lib\\site-packages\\cairo\\include\\py3cairo.h'
      building 'gi._gi' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for pygobject
    Failed to build pygobject
    ERROR: Could not build wheels for pygobject which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

My platform is windows 10 64 bits
```

Comment: It is trying to build. Get the already compiled wheel.

Comment: But how to deal with it?

Comment: Try `pip install pygobject --only-binary pygobject`

Comment: but I got this problem
'''pip install pygobject --only-binary pygobject
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygobject
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygobject
'''